# Bound datasources being updated in non-UI threads

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to use Grpc, which in its example for bi-directional streaming uses this example:

```
using (var call = client.RouteChat())
{
    var responseReaderTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
        {
            //
            // What if I want to update a list bound to a UI 
            // control here?
            //
        }
    });

    foreach (RouteNote request in requests)
    {
        await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
    }
    await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
    await responseReaderTask;
}
```

The problem is that I want to add to a list in the `responseReaderTask`. That list is bound to a dataGridView, and so throws a cross-thread exception. I've seen some examples that say I should change NotifyPropertyChanged to use Invoke? But my current method already does that.

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples you are referring to want you to specifically invoke onto the UI thread. This is different from just a delegate's invoke call.

You're question tag says WinForms, but I'm pretty sure you are looking for a WPF example.

WPF:

```
        while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
        {
            //
            // Use the dispatcher to invoke below onto the UI thread.
            this._someUiControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                // Do UI stuff inside this scope 
            }));
        }
```

WinForms is similar:

```
            // Use a UI control to BeginInvoke onto the UI thread.
            this._someUiControl.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                // Do UI stuff inside this scope 
            }));
```